# And vs semicolon

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, semicolons

In this sentence:

> People were no longer fighting for ideas; they were now fighting simply for money.

it's completely unacceptable to replace the semicolon with a comma + *and* :

> People were no longer fighting for ideas, and they were now fighting simply for money.

What rule of grammar makes it clear that the second example is grammatically incorrect?

Comment: It doesn't seem grammatically incorrect to me, just a bit clunky and awkward to say; hence the improvement by using a semi colon.

Comment: What makes you think the second sentence is grammatically incorrect? I am curious.

Comment: @Rathony it just didn't sound right and I assumed it's a grammar problem. It turned out it wasn't..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a matter of grammar; in your example, *and* fails to indicate the contrast between the first part and the second part. Replace it with another conjunction, *but*, and it works:

> People were no longer fighting for ideas, but they were now fighting simply for money.

The semicolon itself has this contrasting property ['built in'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon#Usage):

> Applications of the semicolon in English include:
>   ...
>   Between closely related independent clauses not conjoined with a coordinating conjunction, when the two clauses are balanced, **opposed** or contradictory

(emphasis mine)

Comment: +1 I'm a fan of using ", rather" to show contrast. It's more of a word choice preference rather than grammar in this example.

Comment: Yeah, there are more words that work here, and 'rather' is one of them.

Comment: Makes sense. BTW, I didn't expect that not indicating the contrast where one is present feels just as bad as an outright misuse of a word.